# iphone posting data to a url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios4

This is the string I need to post http://www.mysite.com/save?details={"name"}

Iam trying the following code;

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"details={\"name\"}"];

```
NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.mysite.com/save?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but the serverOutput always = null,  unless i do just {name}. but i need the qutoes in there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert everythign to valid HTTP symbols.

e.g.:

```
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

...my guess is that your webserver is refusing your invalid URL.

Answer (score 0):

**wrong ..**

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"details={\"name\"}"];

**Correct:**

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithString:@"details={\"name\"}"];

Comment: Thanks But i still have the same error even with trying stringWithString